# LaPlace Transformation DFQ Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[[image: Q1[1]]

I am struggling to move beyond the inverse step of taking the LaPlace general solution.

I know we take
$$\mathcal{L}\{y''\} + 9\mathcal{L}\{y\} = g(t)$$

I know that $\mathcal{L}\{y''\} = s^2$Y(s) - sf(0) - f'(0)$

So then from simple plug and chug, I get that $\mathcal{L}\{y''\} = s^2Y(s) - 1 - 0.$ This is just directly from the IVP problem.

Likewise I know that $\mathcal{L}\{y'\} = sY(s) - y(0)$.

Combining these together into the given equation $y''+9y'= g(t)$

I solve for $Y(s)$ and get $(g(t)+1)/(s^2+9s).$

Up to this point, I am stuck.

Comment: In the right hand side you should have the Laplace transform of $g$. Its computation can be reduced to tabulated transforms using the properties of the Laplace transform, but it is simple enough that a direct computation looks even shorter: $\mathcal{L}(g)=\int_{0}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-st}dt=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-st}dt+\int_{1}^{\infty}te^{-st}dt=-\frac{e^{-s}}{s}+\frac{1}{s}-\frac{e^{-s} (s + 1)}{s^2}$. Now is when you divide by $s^2+9s$. The next task is to compute the inverse Laplace transform of that quotient.

Comment: Your MathJax code was a mess. See my edits for proper usage.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft from your method of computing the transform, how does one immediately know to divide by s^2+9s. Can this be intuitively seen from the problem?

Comment: That comes from what you yourself did on the left hand side of the equation. You computed that $\mathcal{L}(y''+9y')=(s^2+9s)\mathcal{L}(y)$. The whole goal of the method of applying the Laplace transform is to be able to solve for $\mathcal{L}(y)$.

Comment: the g(t) solution differs greatly from the solution posted by Isham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y''+9y'=g(t)$$
Take the Laplace transform of both sides
$$s^2F(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+9(sF(s)-y(0))=\mathcal {L}(g(t))$$
$$s^2F(s)-1+9sF(s)=\mathcal {L}(g(t))$$
$$F(s)(s^2+9s)=1+\mathcal {L}(g(t))$$
You can use the heaviside function
$$g(t)=1(H(t)-H(t-1))+t(H(t-1))$$
$$g(t)=1H(t)+(t-1)(H(t-1))$$
You have also that the laplace transform of
$$\mathcal {L}(H(t-a)f(t-a))=e^{-as}F(s)$$

Therefore
$$\mathcal {L}(g(t))=\frac 1s+\frac {e^{-s}}{s^2}$$
you have now that
$$F(s)(s^2+9s)=1+\frac 1s+\frac {e^{-s}}{s^2}$$
$$F(s)=\frac 1 {s(s+9)}+\frac 1{s^2(s+9)}+\frac {e^{-s}}{s^3(s+9)}$$
You can use fractions decompositions ..

---

For the first fraction we decompose this way
$$h(s)=\frac 1 {s(s+9)}=\frac 19(\frac 1s-\frac 1{s+9})$$
then with the laplace transform table you see that
$$\mathcal{L}(h(s))=\frac 19 (1-e^{-9t})$$

Edit2
for the last fraction dont pay attention to the exponential put it outside
$$f(s)=\frac {e^{-s}}{s^3(s+9)}=e^{-s}\left (\frac {1}{s^3(s+9)} \right)$$
then perform fraction decomposition...the exponential is just a shift

Comment: Isham. Thank you for your response. Why don't we take the inverse of the LaPlace transform?

Comment: decompose the fraction so you can take the inverse Laplace transform thats the last step ...@SleepApnea

Comment: the first fraction would thus decompose into sin(3t), the second fraction will decompose into sin^-1(3t). What transform contains e^s in its numerator? Thank you for your help

Comment: @SleepApnea Sorry i just saw your comment and question I added some lines please check

Comment: Hi Isham. Thank you for your response. I was wondering why the poster above, spiraltotheleft, attained such a drastically different LHS than your solution. Even after dividing by s^2 + 9, I failed to match your g(t)

Comment: I think he has a sign mistake...Did you evaluate the integral ? Normally it should give the same result as qith Heaviside method @SleepApnea

Comment: Yes I did. I got the same solution as you did. But I was worried that his reputation points were pretty high, I thought I may have made a mistake. Thank you for your response.

Can you explain how to decompose the third fraction decomposition? I am unfamiliar with e^xt terms on the numerator

Comment: Sign mistakes happen to everyone @SleepApnea  look at Wolfram Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7De%5E%7B-st%7Ddt%2B%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Dte%5E%7B-st%7Ddt

Comment: Can you explain how to decompose the third fraction decomposition? I am unfamiliar with e^xt terms on the numerator .

Comment: I aded some lines for the last fraction @SleepApnea

Comment: shouldn't the second fraction be 9s as opposed to be 9

Comment: @SleepApnea where exactly ?

Comment: it should be 1/s^2(s+9s)

Comment: @SleepApnea  no we had an s already at the denomintor then we multiply by $(s^2+9s)$ we get $s(s^2+9s)=s^2(s+9)$

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I made a mistake. You are absolutely right.

Mr. Isham. If it is at all convenient for you, can you please post some insights into this question as well? 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872881/wave-equation-need-clarification-please

Comment: Will look at that question ...you will get some answers it takes a little time...

Comment: Thank you kind sir

Comment: yw @SleepApnea..............